# Exporting NDVI as .TIF using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, ndvi, geotiff-tiff, error-000732

Here is my code so far:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")


workspace = arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/KJanus/Desktop/Intro_ArcGIS/RasterData_Lab6"
arcpy.CreateFolder_management(workspace, "NDVI")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


RED_1 = arcpy.Raster("C:/Users/KJanus/Desktop/Intro_ArcGIS/RasterData_Lab6/landtm1.img/Layer_3")
NIR_1 = arcpy.Raster("C:/Users/KJanus/Desktop/Intro_ArcGIS/RasterData_Lab6/landtm1.img/Layer_4")

RED_2 = arcpy.Raster("C:/Users/KJanus/Desktop/Intro_ArcGIS/RasterData_Lab6/landtm2.img/Layer_3")
NIR_2 = arcpy.Raster("C:/Users/KJanus/Desktop/Intro_ArcGIS/RasterData_Lab6/landtm2.img/Layer_4")

RED_3 = arcpy.Raster("C:/Users/KJanus/Desktop/Intro_ArcGIS/RasterData_Lab6/landtm3.img/Layer_3")
NIR_3 = arcpy.Raster("C:/Users/KJanus/Desktop/Intro_ArcGIS/RasterData_Lab6/landtm3.img/Layer_4")

print "Program recognizes raster bands."

NDVI_1 = (NIR_1 - RED_1)/(NIR_1 + RED_1)

sr = arcpy.sa.Con(RED_1<>0, NDVI_1, -9999)

NDVI_2 = (NIR_2 - RED_2)/(NIR_2 + RED_2)

sr = arcpy.sa.Con(RED_2<>0, NDVI_2, -9999)

NDVI_3 = (NIR_3 - RED_3)/(NIR_3 + RED_3)

sr = arcpy.sa.Con(RED_3<>0, NDVI_3, -9999)


print "NDVIs passed"


arcpy.CopyRaster_management("NDVI_1", "C:/Users/KJanus/Desktop/Intro_ArcGIS/RasterData_Lab6/NDVI", 
format= "TIFF")
```

When I run the code I get these two errors: ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset NDVI_1 does not exist or is not supported

Comment: What happened when you run the code?

Comment: sr is being overwritten twice, do you want the 3 X sr to be the 3 bands of a raster? If so make the variables sr1, sr2 and sr3 then use CompositeBands_management([sr1,sr2,sr3], "C:/Users/KJanus/Desktop/Intro_ArcGIS/RasterData_Lab6/NDVI/NDVI_1.tif") http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000009p000000 - Arc is smart enough to understand you want to export to GeoTIFF format if you supply the file extension. Also I believe that Not Equals is != in Con http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000z7000000 and -9999 isn't a good value to use.

Comment: It will promote the pixels from 8 bit unsigned to 32 bit signed integer type.. which will cause havoc in trying to use the data in a 3 band image. I can see the code but as @ahmadhanb is alluding, what is the *actual* problem you're having?

Comment: When I run the code I get these two errors:  ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset NDVI_1 does not exist or is not supported

Answer (score 3):

This should be the correct syntax:

```
NDVI_1.save("C:/Users/KJanus/Desktop/Intro_ArcGIS/RasterData_Lab6/NDVI.tif")
```

Comment: That is true for a single band but we're not really sure what the actual problem is. Still, you are correct so +1 from me.

Comment: Yes, the code is a bit vague so I just went with the simple answer.

Comment: Oh sweet.  It works!  Yeah I'm extremely new to arcpy and python in general so my code is still clunky, but it's getting there.  Thanks Dan.

Comment: Looking at your band syntax, it doesn't look quite right K.J. Are you sure the bands are called 'Layer_'? If you browse to the rasters in ArcCatalog in contents view are the bands called Layer_1, Layer_2 etc or is it Band_1, Band_2 etc..?

Comment: It's Layer_n with n ranging from 1 to 7.  It comes from landsat TM data